# Why isn't typescript showing an error? (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a container as follows:

```
lass BurgerBuilder extends React.Component {

state = {
    ingredients: {
        salad: 1,
        bacon: 1,
        cheese: 2, 
        meat: 2
    }
}
render() {
    return(
        <>
            <Burger ingredients={this.state.ingredients}/>
            <div>Build Controls</div>
        </>
    );
}
}
```

My Burger functional component includes the following code

```
export interface IBurgerProps {
    ingredients: {
        salad?: number,
        bacon?: number,
        cheese?: number, 
        meat?: number
    }
}

const burger = (props: IBurgerProps) =>{
    const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map(igKey=> {
        return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
            <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey}/>
        })
    });
```

Theoretically, if I add "chicken: 1" to the ingredient object in my container (BurgerBuilder), I should get an error. I.e, typescript should complain saying we can't assign { salad: number, bacon: number, cheese: number, meat: number, chicken: number } to type { salad: number | undefined, bacon: number | undefined, cheese: number | undefined, meat: number | undefined}

Why is it that I don't get this error when I add "chicken: 1" to the ingredients object in Burger Builder?

Just trying to understand typing and react more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript uses what's called a *substructural type system*, which means as long as your object has everything you asked from it, the rest doesn't really matter.

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-284590083) around the topic of introducing *exact types* to the language. Today one needs to employ some questionable tricks to make it work.

In the meantime, I recommend describing the contract between your components with an interface. In this case, `Ingredients` are the interface — it's what both components depend on.

Let's abstract it from your component. An example model could look like this:

```
type IngredientName =
  | 'salad'
  | 'bacon'
  | 'cheese'
  | 'meat';

type Ingredients = Record<IngredientName, number>
```

Usage:

```
interface Props {}

interface State {
    ingredients: Ingredients;
}

export class BurgerBuilder extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
        ingredients: {
            salad: 1,
            bacon: 1,
            cheese: 2,
            meat: 2,
            chicken: 2, // Error! Chicken is not on the list.
        },
    };
}
```

You can read more about type relationships [in the specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#311-type-relationships).